# How to convert outputStream to a byte array?

Tags: java

How can I convert an OutputStream to a byte array? I have found that first I need to convert this OutputStream to a ByteArrayOutputStream. There is only write() method in this OutputStream class and I don't know what to do. Is there any idea?

Comment: Use [toByteArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#toByteArray()) to extract the bytes

Comment: Strictly speaking, you can't. An output stream is an output stream is an output stream. Once it exists, you could maybe wrap it in a PrintStream or something.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Create a `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

Grab its content by calling `toByteArray()`

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
baos.writeTo(myOutputStream); 
baos.toByteArray();
```

[Reference](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_bytearrayoutputstream.htm)

Comment: For those clueless like me:

`ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();`
`baos.writeTo(myOutputStream);`
`baos.toByteArray();`

Comment: Side question. Are there any limitations to `baos.toString()` compared to `baos.toByteArray()`? I have used it first on some old projects but for some reason, I was not able to generate an SHA-1 hash digest from it but was working fine for the second one and still I have no clue why may be something in the reading file.

Comment: Although this is a highly voted and accepted answer, it does not actually answer the question. The code in this answer shows how to write the contents of an empty ByteArrayOutputStream to another OutputStream myOutputStream via the writeTo method. If the idea was to demonstrate that ByteArrayOutputStream has a toByteArray method, then the intermediate baos.writeTo(myOutputStream) should instead be more like baos.write(new byte[] {1,2,3}), to demonstrate that those same bytes are then present in the toByteArray() call.

Answer (score 7):

If the `OutputStream` object supplied is not already a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, one can `wrap` it inside a delegate class that will "grab" the bytes supplied to the `write()` methods, e.g.

```
public class DrainableOutputStream extends FilterOutputStream {
  private final ByteArrayOutputStream buffer;
  public DrainableOutputStream(OutputStream out) {
    super(out);
    this.buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  }
  @Override
  public void write(byte b[]) throws IOException {
    this.buffer.write(b);
    super.write(b);
  }
  @Override
  public void write(byte b[], int off, int len) throws IOException {
    this.buffer.write(b, off, len);
    super.write(b, off, len);
  }
  @Override
  public void write(int b) throws IOException {
    this.buffer.write(b);    
    super.write(b);
  }
  public byte[] toByteArray() {
    return this.buffer.toByteArray();
  }
}
```

To reduce the overhead, the calls to `super` in the above class can be omitted - e.g., if only the "conversion" to a byte array is desired.

A more detailed discussion can be found in [another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43081008/converting-outputstream-to-byte-array).

Answer (score 4):

You need to do 2 things

- Using ByteArrayOutputStream write to it
- Using toByteArray(), you will get the contents as byte[]

You could even extend it as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15686667/548634)

Answer (score 1):

You could simply declare your output stream as a `ByteArrayOutputStream` then use `ByteArrayOutputStream#toByteArray()`.

Answer (score -1):

If You try `ByteArrayOutputStream bos=(ByteArrayOutputStream)outputStream`  then throw `ClassCastException`.
I did it when I get `OutputStream` from `HttpServletResponse` and it is `CoyoteOutputStream`.(You can create file so dont create file temp).

You can use `Java Reflection` to convert `OutputStream` to `byte[]`:

```
 byte[] bytes = this.getBytes(outStream);

/**
 * Get byte from OutputStream
 *
 * @param outStream
 * @return
 */
@SneakyThrows
private byte[] getBytes(OutputStream outStream) {
    OutputBuffer outputBuffer = (OutputBuffer) this.getValueByName("ob", outStream);
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = (ByteBuffer) this.getValueByName("bb", outputBuffer);
    return (byte[]) this.getValueByName("hb", byteBuffer);
}

/**
 * Get value from property
 *
 * @param name
 * @param value
 * @return
 */
@SneakyThrows
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private Object getValueByName(String name, Object value) {
    List<Field> listFiled = new ArrayList<>();
    if (value.getClass().getSuperclass() != null) {
        listFiled.addAll(Arrays.asList(value.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredFields()));
    }
    listFiled.addAll(Arrays.asList(value.getClass().getDeclaredFields()));
    Optional<Field> fieldOb = listFiled.stream()
        .filter(field -> StringUtils.equalsAnyIgnoreCase(name, field.getName()))
        .findFirst();
    if (fieldOb.isPresent()) {
        Field field = fieldOb.get();
        field.setAccessible(true);
        return field.get(value);
    }
    return StringUtils.EMPTY; // FIXME
}
```

Comment: Which OutputStream classes have fields ob and bb?