# converting outputStream to byte array

Tags: java, java-io, outputstream

How can I get the bytes of an outputStream, or how can I convert an outputStream to a byte array?

Comment: Are you sure you are talking about an [`OutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html) and not an [`InputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html)?

Comment: [ByteArrayOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) is what you're looking for.

Comment: @domdom im talking about OutputStream

Comment: @DumpCake i've been through that answer, but it did not fit with my needs

Comment: @Obicere can you explain more ?

Comment: That depends, what exactly are you trying to accomplish? What are your "needs"?

Comment: @Obicere i have two methods, as output of the first one, i get an outputstream
and as an input of my second method, i need to pass a byte array with the content of the outputStream.
so, what i need is to convert the resulted output stream to a byte array

Comment: Showing code will make this easier and will help portray what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From a theoretical perspective (i.e., irrespective of whether it makes sense in practice as a use case), this is an interesting question that essentially requires the implementation of a method like

```
public abstract byte[] convert(OutputStream out);
```

The [`Java` `OutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html) class, as its name implies, only supports an overridden `write()` method for I/O, and that `write()` method gets either an integer (representing 1 byte) or a `byte` array, the contents of which it sends to an output (e.g., a file).

For example, the following code saves the bytes already present in the `data` array, to the `output.txt` file:

```
byte[] data = ... // Get some data
OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("path/to/output.txt");
fos.write(data);
```

In order to get all the data that a given `OutputStream` will be outputting and put it into a `byte` array (i.e., into a `byte[]` object), the class from which the corresponding `OutputStream` object was instantiated, should keep storing all the bytes processed via its `write()` methods and provide a special method, such as `toByteArray()`, that would return them all, upon invocation.

This is exactly what the `ByteArrayOutputStream` class does, making the `convert()` method trivial (and unnecessary):

```
public byte[] convert(ByteArrayOutputStream out) {
  return out.toByteArray();
}
```

For any other type of `OutputStream`, not inherently supporting a similar conversion to a `byte[]` object, there is no way to make the conversion, before the `OutputStream` is drained, i.e. before the desired calls to its `write()` methods have been completed.

If such an assumption (of the writes to have been completed) can be made, and if the original `OutputStream` object can be replaced, then one option is to wrap it inside a delegate class that would essentially "grab" the bytes that would be supplied via its `write()` methods. For example:

```
public class DrainableOutputStream extends FilterOutputStream {
  private final ByteArrayOutputStream buffer;
  public DrainableOutputStream(OutputStream out) {
    super(out);
    this.buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  }
  @Override
  public void write(byte b[]) throws IOException {
    this.buffer.write(b);
    super.write(b);
  }
  @Override
  public void write(byte b[], int off, int len) throws IOException {
    this.buffer.write(b, off, len);
    super.write(b, off, len);
  }
  @Override
  public void write(int b) throws IOException {
    this.buffer.write(b);    
    super.write(b);
  }
  public byte[] toByteArray() {
    return this.buffer.toByteArray();
  }
}
```

The calls to the `write()` methods of the internal "buffer" (`ByteArrayOutputStream`) precede the calls to the original stream (which, in turn, can be accessed via `super`, or even via `this.out`, since the corresponding parameter of the `FilterOutputStream` is `protected`). This makes sure that the bytes will be buffered, even if there is an exception while writing to the original stream.

To reduce the overhead, the calls to `super` in the above class can be omitted - e.g., if only the "conversion" to a `byte` array is desired. Even the `ByteArrayOutputStream` or `OutputStream` classes can be used as parent classes, with a bit more work and some assumptions (e.g., about the `reset()` method).

In any case, enough memory has to be available for the draining to take place and for the `toByteArray()` method to work.

Comment: thank you for the extended explanations, it helps me to understand things better

Answer (score 6):

For @Obicere comment example:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream btOs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
btOs.write("test bytes".getBytes());    
String restoredString = new String(btOs.toByteArray());
System.out.println(restoredString);
```