# How to convert TarArchiveOutputStream to byte array without saving into file system

Tags: java, tar, apache-commons-compress

I have a byte array representation of a tar.gz file. I want to get the byte array representation of a new tar.gz file after adding a new config file. I wanted to do this entirely in the code itself without creating any files to the local disk.

Below is my code in java

```
            InputStream fIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(inputBytes);
            BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(fIn);
            GzipCompressorInputStream gzIn = new GzipCompressorInputStream(in);
            TarArchiveInputStream tarInputStream = new TarArchiveInputStream(gzIn);

            ByteArrayOutputStream fOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            BufferedOutputStream buffOut = new BufferedOutputStream(fOut);
            GzipCompressorOutputStream gzOut = new GzipCompressorOutputStream(buffOut);
            TarArchiveOutputStream tarOutputStream = new TarArchiveOutputStream(gzOut);

            ArchiveEntry nextEntry;
            while ((nextEntry = tarInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                tarOutputStream.putArchiveEntry(nextEntry);
                IOUtils.copy(tarInputStream, tarOutputStream);
                tarOutputStream.closeArchiveEntry();
            }
            tarInputStream.close();
            createTarArchiveEntry("config.json", configData, tarOutputStream);
            tarOutputStream.finish();
            // Convert tarOutputStream to byte array and return





    private static void createTarArchiveEntry(String fileName, byte[] configData, TarArchiveOutputStream tOut)
            throws IOException {

        ByteArrayInputStream baOut1 = new ByteArrayInputStream(configData);

        TarArchiveEntry tarEntry = new TarArchiveEntry(fileName);
        tarEntry.setSize(configData.length);
        tOut.putArchiveEntry(tarEntry);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = baOut1.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            tOut.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        tOut.closeArchiveEntry();

    }
```

How to convert tarOuputStream to byte array?

Comment: You don't need to, you already have it. `ByteArrayOutputStream fOut` is the output stream which contains your byte array. Use the `toByteArray()` method, see other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23154009/how-to-convert-outputstream-to-a-byte-array

Comment: @Progman I obtained a byte array from fOut as you said. But the new config file's data is not getting stored in that array. That means after converting that byte array to tar.gz file at some location in my local disk the contents of that file are same as previous one ie., config.json file is not added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have opened the several `OutputStream` instances, but you haven't closed them yet. Or more precisely, you haven't "flushed" the content, specially the `BufferedOutputStream` instance.

`BufferedOutputStream` is using an internal buffer to "wait" for the data written to the target `OutputStream`. It does so until there is a reason to do so. One of these "reasons" is to call the [`BufferedOutputStream.flush()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html#flush()) method:

> `public void flush() throws IOException`
>
> Flushes this buffered output stream. This forces any buffered output bytes to be written out to the
> underlying output stream.

One other "reason" is to close the stream so it will write the remaining bytes before closing the stream.

In your case the bytes being written are still stored in the internal buffer. Depending on your code structure, you can simply close all the `OutputStream` instances you have, so the bytes finally gets written to the `ByteArrayOutputStream`:

```
tarInputStream.close();
createTarArchiveEntry("config.json", configData, tarOutputStream);
tarOutputStream.finish();
// Convert tarOutputStream to byte array and return
tarOutputStream.close();
gzOut.close();
buffOut.close();
fOut.close();

byte[] content = fOut.toByteArray();
```